# MySQL Data Source Entity in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2012, entitydatasource

I have also encountered the problem to create a data source in VS2012 with MySQL connector, while many thanks for the connector updates from Oracle.

Than I installed the MySQL connector version 6.6.5, it looks work well while there is no directory in the "Data Source" sub-window but the Model has been created after I created the data source.

When I configuring the insert process to the data using Linq, VS2012 tells there is no such method "AddTo".

Therefore, according the things happened during my programming:

1. Is it common that the data source will not be shown in that sub window after I have already add the data entities?
2. Why there is no such method "AddTo" (Actually no any methods at all in the definition) when I using Linq with VS2012?

Many thanks in advance,

Harry